# Conflict between breqn, bm and pslatex packages

Tags: breqn, bm

If I use bm, breqn and pslatex packages together, whenever I type a symbol using `\bm`, it prints it three times in different sizes.

For example, the following code (I'm using online latex editor - overleaf.com. It does not show any error for this code),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pslatex, breqn, bm}

\begin{document}
$\bm{\theta}$
\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: theta three times]

If I remove either breqn or pslatex packages, I do not have this problem. Is there any way to use all three packages together without such problems?

The manual says something about overprinting three times, poor man's bold and providing an offset of -1, but I do not understand it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you perhaps using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Thank you @egreg. I'm actually using overleaf.com. I'm not sure what latex they are using.

Comment: Can you add a very minimal example of code?

Comment: @egreg, I have already added a very simple example to my question. Let me know if you want me to add another example.

Comment: No, a complete document that people can run to make the imag ethat you show.

Comment: A minimal document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: unrelated but don't use math italic for multi-letter symbols such as `old` the font is designed to make it not look like a word, but as a product of variables, use `_{\mathit{old}}` or `_{\mathrm{old}}`

Comment: Thank you all. I'm sorry that I didn't get it in the first read. I understand what it means now. I also understood that it is a very good way to debug our problem. Through this method, I figured that the problem is caused by another candidate - pslatex. This problem happens only when all three packages are included - bm, pslatex, breqn. I have updated my question and description accordingly with the minimal code. Thank you again.

Comment: you don't want to use pslatex at all (I wrote it and I haven't used it since about 1995)

Comment: Ah _if_ you load pslatex first you get an _error_ `! Argument of \bm@pmb@@ has an extra }.` You should have stated that you had an errro not shown the screen shot, after an error the typeset output from TeX is, by design, not intended to be sensible it just recovers in any way to syntax check the rest of the file. There is no point really looking at the pdf in such a case.

Comment: @David Carlisle, Thank you David. I followed your advice of loading pslatex after bm and breqn and it worked fine!

Comment: @omsrisagar *Don't load* `pslatex`: it's an obsolete package. If you want Times, do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead.

Comment: well it doesn't work at all. You get no error but the bold theta comes from computer modern not times, my advice would be not to use pslatex. Use for example newtxmath to get times-like maths, pslatex was designed just to use the built in fonts in a sun (apple) laser writer around 1990. It serves no purpose whatsoever now.

Comment: oh no, I'm agreeing with @egreg, something must be wrong.

Comment: @egreg, @David Carlisle, thank you both for your valuable suggestions. Actually speaking, I do not know why I was using `pslatex` package. I copied all the packages from one of my previous papers (seems like pslatex is included since long time). From now on, I will instead use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` in case I need similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `pslatex` unless you are using an apple/sun laser writer from around 1990 and want to use its built in fonts.

use for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}



($\bm{\theta_{\mathit{old}}}$) ($\theta_{\mathit{old}}$)



\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}

($\bm{\theta_{old}}$)

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Please post a complete small document, as above, which produces the bad output that you show.

with pslatex as mentioned in comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}

($\bm{\theta_{old}}$)

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Argument of \bm@pmb@@ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ($\bm{\theta_{old}}
                       $)
? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \bm@pmb@@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9 ($\bm{\theta_{old}}
                       $)
?
```

Comment: Thank you David. I'm using overleaf.com, it doesn't show any error but shows that weird output. As per your comment, I tried loading pslatex after bm and breqn and it works fine! Thank you. The problem is solved. You can add that the solution is to load pslatex after bm and breqn.

Comment: @omsrisagar No that is not the solution!!!!

Comment: @omsrisagar I have updated the answer with a solution (at the top, before the line)

Comment: thank you David. I get this error if I include newtx packages after bm and breqn - "Command \dfrac already defined.              Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual." Probably this is a known issue?

Comment: @omsrisagar it makes no sense to load font packages after bm newtx should be loaded first, as shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42729/discussion-between-omsrisagar-and-david-carlisle).